# Splitting a string in C#, why is this not working?

Tags: c#, text

I have the following string:

> string myString = " The objective for test.\vVision\v* Deliver a test
>   goals\v**  Comprehensive\v** Control\v* Alignment with cross-Equities
>   strategy\vApproach\v*An acceleration "

and I am trying to split on "\v"

I tried this but it doesn't seem to work:

```
char[] delimiters = new char[] { '\v' };
string[] split = myString.Split(delimiters);
for (int i = 0; i < split.Length; i++) {
}
```

`split.Length` shows up as 1.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Looks like you are not escaping the backslash.

Comment: I run your code and the Length == 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like this

```
string[] separators = {@"\v"};
      string value = @"The objective for test.\vVision\v* Deliver a test goals\v** Comprehensive\v** Control\v* Alignment with cross-Equities strategy\vApproach\v*An acceleration";
      string[] words = value.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 6):

`"\v"` is two characters, not one, in your original string (which is not counting the `\` as an escape character as a literal C# string does).

You need to be splitting on literal `"\v"` which means you need to specify the overload of Split that takes a string:

```
string[] split = narrative.Split(new string[] {"\\v"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Note how I had to escape the "\" character with "\\"

Your `'\v'` is a single control character, not two characters.

I think your question itself is slightly misleading...

Your example string, if entered into C# will actually work like you expected, because a  `\v` in a verbatum C# string will be escaped to a special character:

```
string test = " The objective for test.\vVision\v* Deliver a test goals\v** Comprehensive\v** Control\v* Alignment with cross-Equities strategy\vApproach\v*An acceleration ";

char[] delimiters = new char[] { '\v' };
Console.WriteLine(test.Split(delimiters).Length); // Prints 8
```

However, I think your actual string really does have backslash-v in it rather than escaped \v:

```
string test = " The objective for test.\\vVision\\v* Deliver a test goals\\v** Comprehensive\\v** Control\\v* Alignment with cross-Equities strategy\\vApproach\\v*An acceleration ";

char[] delimiters = new char[] { '\v' };
Console.WriteLine(test.Split(delimiters).Length); // Prints 1, like you say you see.
```

So you can fix it as described above by using an array of strings to split the string:

```
string test = " The objective for test.\\vVision\\v* Deliver a test goals\\v** Comprehensive\\v** Control\\v* Alignment with cross-Equities strategy\\vApproach\\v*An acceleration ";

string[] delimiters = new [] { "\\v" };
Console.WriteLine(test.Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.None).Length); // Prints 8
```

Comment: Well, if we follow C# notation, the string `"\v"` is one character (length of string is one), whereas `@"\v"` and `"\\v"` both denote the same length-two string. Also note that the debugger will often use the format where ``\`` is an escape character.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Aye, but the OP is showing us text for which "\v" is really two characters, not an escaped one. It's a bit misleading, but it clearly is two characters otherwise his split would have worked.

Answer (score -1):

Use Like this,

```
string myString = " The objective for test.\vVision\v* Deliver a test goals\v** Comprehensive\v** Control\v* Alignment with cross-Equities strategy\vApproach\v*An acceleration";
string[] delimiters = new string[] { "\v" };
string[] split = myString.Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.None);
for (int i = 1; i < split.Length; i++)
{
}
```

Comment: @Down Voter, Care to Comment?

Comment: I didn't downvote but you don't need to escape the string. At the moment your code won't split the string.

Comment: I didn't downvote this answer. But it seems to be an equivalent of an earlier answer by Matthew Watson. Maybe this is the reason why somebody voted the answer down.

Comment: @keyboardP, Did you try this code. Just Copy n Paste in VS it will work. try it now

Comment: @defaultlocale, I agree, But see the time who answered first.

Comment: @PrasadKanaparthi - Split length is `1` for me

Comment: @keyboardP, Actually the string in this question got changed. Yes '\' is not required. Edited my post. Thanks.

Comment: @PrasadKanaparthi double-checked the timing :) Another answer is ahead by 4 min 10 sec.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't need the resulting array for later use, you can combine the split and loop into one call.

```
foreach (string s in myString.Split(new[] { "\v" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
{
   //s is the string you can now use in your loop
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try running it like this.

```
       public static string FirstName(string fullName)
        {
            if (fullName == null)
                return null;
            var split = fullName.Split(',');
            return split.Length > 0 ? split[0] : string.Empty;
        }
```